# Ruby - more accurate timestamp than Time.now.utc

Tags: ruby

Normally I use `Time.now.utc` for the timestamp in my project. But this time it looks it's not accurate enough to just use `Time.now.utc`.

It looks that `Time.now.utc` is on second level(is it correct?), is not as accurate as I want.

Is there ways to generate timestamp on milliseconds level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Time](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-c-new) docs:

> The object created will be created using the resolution available on your system clock, and so may include fractional seconds.

Examples:

```
a = Time.new 
"%.6f" % a.to_f

=> "1334402161.334542"
```

Answer (score 8):

According to [the documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html):

> Time is stored internally as the number of seconds with fraction since the Epoch, January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC

You can access the internal float representation using the [`to_f`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#to_f-method) method, e.g.

```
irb> Time.now.to_f
=> 1334401921.06418
```

Or you can use the [`strftime`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) method to print it out nicely, e.g.:

```
irb> Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%L")
=> "2012-04-14 21:20:58.100"
```

(In theory at least, I can't get `%L` to work on Ruby 1.8, but it does work on 1.9)

Comment: For even more precision, you can use (eg) `%6N` for 6 digits (microseconds). [The docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime) show a max precision of 24 digits (yoctoseconds), but you can do `%1000N` if you want. Of course, your CPU can't even perform a single instruction in that fraction of time, and Ruby adds a lot of overhead, so the large precisions are just theoretical.